# How to optimize the running of Oracle orderby native query running in EJB (Oc4j)?

Tags: performance, oracle, ejb, sql-order-by

I've the following problem with EJB and Oracle database.

I've some native SQL query deployed in Oc4j that returns more than 21k rows from Oracle DB. when I run the query against Oracle DB I get JOOM (out of memory) exception.

And because the requirements was to include pagination for the result set, so we decided to use em.setMaxResult, em.setFirstResult to return only 10 rows a time.

Using the `EntityManager` to implement the pagination put us in some problem As Later, it was required to sort the result returned, but the whole result not just the 10 rows returned by `setMaxResult()`! We found that, to put the clause `ORDER BY xxxx` in the native query makes the query performance became too bad.

So, we are considering doing the pagination in the Database layer (using Oracle rownum or any other technique).

Later, we recognized  that, If we use [`em.clear()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear%28%29) we might be able to avoid the JOOM exception by making something like:

```
define the result list
while database has more records
{
   use entityManager get next 10 records and add them to the result list
   entityManager.clear();
}
return result list
```

So, we could implement the paging on the Servlet side (using `session.getAttribute("all_result").sublist(from, to)`) and thus we can do the sort using Java as opposite to SQL sort.

Answer (score 0):

Provided code for pagination, might help you.

```
em.createQuery("Select o from Entity o where o.id > :lastId order by o.id");
query.setParameter("lastId", previousResult.get(previousResult.size()-1).getId());
query.setMaxResults(10);
```